# Taylor expansion of this electric field

Tags: taylor-expansion, approximation

I'm trying to determine what happens when R>>z for the below equation

> $\frac{z\sigma}{2\varepsilon }\left ( \frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{R^{2}+z^{2}}} \right )$

Like most books, which is a great annoyance, authors 'talk' about numerical approximation, asymptotic expansion, approximation technique without showing anything of sufficiency

The authors says that taylor expansion gives

> $E=\frac{Q}{4\pi \varepsilon z^{2}}$

Which is utterly unhelpful and of no use for a student trying to figure the vagaries of *his* work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not a physicist, so I'm wondering how there is a $Q$ in the equation below but there is not in the above. So how could you have gotten the second from the first by a Taylor approximation?

Comment: This is also where the author left me feeling confused.

What I get is
$f\left ( R \right )=\frac{1}{\sqrt{R^{2}+z^{2}]}}$

Taylor approximation gives(for second order terms) 
$\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{z^{3}}$
@Jake

Answer (score 1):

I think there's typo in your text, it'll be reasonable for $z>>R$ instead:

\begin{align*}
  \frac{z\sigma}{2\varepsilon}
  \left( \frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{R^{2}+z^{2}}} \right) &=
  \frac{z\sigma}{2\varepsilon}
  \left[
    \frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{z}\left( 1-\frac{R^{2}}{2z^{2}} \right)
  \right] \\
  &= \sigma \times \frac{R^{2}}{4z^{2}\varepsilon} \\
  &= \frac{Q}{4\pi R^{2}} \times \frac{R^{2}}{4z^{2}\varepsilon}
\end{align*}

The coefficient still not agrees, please double check all the contexts you have.